# and a serie of flags

Tags: assembly, x86-64

i'm trying to put my terminal in raw mode in x86-64 assembly, i wonder if there's a better way to do it than :

```
   mov    eax, IGNBRK                                                              
   not    eax
   and    dword [termios], eax                                                     

   mov    eax, BRKINT                                                                      
   not    eax
   and    dword [termios], eax                                                     

   mov    eax, PARMRK                                                              
   not    eax
   and    dword [termios], eax

etc...
```

Comment: There is no reason to do arithmetic at runtime on compile time constants. You can just `and dword [termios], ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK)` or whatever you need. Use the syntax appropriate for your assembler.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, this makes sense, and sorry for the stupid question, i'm new in assembly and sometimes documentation overwhelmed me ^^

Comment: @LeytereNephae No need to be sorry!  Have fun with your journey through assembly programming!